# How to append two numpy arrays if a for loop after loading data?

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays. I want to append then along zero axis. If I use np.append command it demands two arguments. Whereas the following code loads first array and then second array. How I can implement np.append command in this case? I read different commands like np.concatenate and np.vstack but I don't know how to implement it in for loop. Can someone please guide me about this.

```
`list=[1,2]
for i in list:
    s=np.load("%s.npy"%i)
    r=np.append(s,axis=0)
    print(s)
    print(s.shape)`
```

Comment: Naming variables like builtins is not a good idea, in this case `list = [1, 2]` shadows the builtin function `list()`.

Comment: Do not use `np.append`.  Ever! Collect  values in a list (list append is great).  Concatenate once.

Comment: `np.append` has several problems.  It's a poorly written and badly used front end to `concatenate`.  It is not a list append clone.  Used iteratively this approach is slow.  It is also hard to get the initial `empty` right (you have to understand array dimensions well).

Comment: Should i use store arrays in a list  ss and then concatenate it outside loop by np.concatenate(ss,axis=0).?

Comment: "it is poorly witten and badly used front end to concatenate". Can you please explain this

Answer (score 0):

You can load everything in a list of arrays and concatenate that list together to one array:

```
r = np.concatenate([np.random.rand(5, 5) for i in [1, 2]], axis=0)
```

Comment: Yes I am storing data in a list =[(3,2),(3,2)], list stores several numpy array. Now I want to concatenate. But it appends along row axis without specifying axis

Comment: If i use np.concatenate(ss,axis=0) code works fine but when I use np.append(ss,axis=0) it doesn't work

Comment: I have removed the one using empty as I couldn't get it to work.